# Drupal private directory conditional htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-8

I want my htaccess to work only when current user has no access to the specific node.

I have a private directory within Files in my drupal 8 project.
I would like to know if something like this (bellow) could work and how.

```
If (user_has_access) {}
else {somehow disable htaccess}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to setup an [$_ENVs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) flag during the application startup. This flag will be a variable defined on the server and the you case use it like

```
<IFDefine {variable}>
{executable code}
</IFDefine>
```

You need to add this flag in Drupal 8's bootstrap function and then include all your executable .htaccess code within the IFDefine block. So if flag is set or defined the code will execute otherwise not. But still the .htaccess loads and functional. This way you can save this file for other purpose as well.

Hope it might help!